# Stop progation for twitter bootstrap's dropdown

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I want to prevent closing of dropdowns after clicking on their menu items. Here is what I'm doing:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $(document).on("click", ".dropdown-menu li", function(event){
        debugger; // it stops here though
        event.stopPropagation();
      });
 });
```

but dropdowns become closed after clicking on any their menu item. What am I doing wrong?

**P.S.** I have to use `$(document).on("click", ".dropdown-menu li"`, because this dropdown is dynamically built by ajax.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For some reason only this solution is working

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".dropdown-menu").on("click", "li", function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    });
  });
```

does anybody know why?

Comment: I thought I explained *why*?

Comment: @deceze `$(".dropdown-menu").on("click", "li",`

Comment: Please use the *Post answer* button only for actual answers. You should modify your original question to add additional information.

Answer (score 2):

If you bind the handler on the `document`, the event will already have travelled up all the way to the top and will have already triggered the event handlers that close the menu. You need to bind the handler to the element being clicked on and stop it right there from propagating if you want to catch it before it reaches the Bootstrap handlers.

```
$('.dropdown-menu li').on('click', ...)
```

Comment: (Having said this I don't know exactly where Bootstrap binds its handlers and if there's an opportunity at all to squeeze a handler in between.)

Comment: I have to use `$(document).on("click", ".dropdown-menu li",` because this dropdown is dynamically built by ajax. So I have to use document. What should I do then to make it stop propogation?

Comment: That's no reason to bind to `document`. Try using a `live` handler on an element further down (probably problematic for the same reason) or attach the event handler to the new element every time after building and inserting a new menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can write it this way :

```
$(".dropdown-menu li").on("click", function(event){
 event.stopPropagation();


 });
```